# I can't click to attack - Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My trackpad refuses to click to attack. When I'm in forge, it works perfectly fine, but when I'm in normal Minecraft 1.11.2 or 1.12, it won't work (it doesn't work in single player or on a multiplayer server). I've tried:

- Using a mouse
- Reinstalling Minecraft
- Deleting the servers and added them again

Nothing has worked.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Does the mouse work in other areas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe you have something else set to activate when click check controls in settings or maybe your right clicking not left clicking